# Summing Odd Values In A Data Range: Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a data set (I10:I18) containing the numbers 1-9 sequentially and I am trying to sum only the odd values within the set. The following formula seems like it should work but I keep getting a value of "0".

=SUMIF(I10:I18,IF(MOD(I10:I18,2)=1,I10:I18,0)

I realize adding the odd numbers in this example could easily be done without the formula. I am just practicing my excel skills. If someone could help me find the error I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: When I copy the formula from linked page it still does not produce the correct value after entering my data ranges

Comment: I was able to make it work. Did you use the formula from the question or the answer? And did you make it an array?

Comment: Ahh, right on. I didn't make it an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(I10:I18)*(MOD(I10:I18,2)=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Yep that works, thanks. However I am still curious what was wrong with the original formula.